# JavaScript splice problem

Tags: javascript, splice

A have an array of Objects and I'd like to remove the first element from it and read some of its properties. But I can't. Here is the code:

```
$.test = function(){
 var array = [
  {a: "a1", b: "b1"},
  {a: "a2", b: "b2"},
  {a: "a3", b: "b3"}
 ];
 alert("0. element's 'a': " + array[0].a); 
 alert("length: " + array.length);

 var element = array.splice(0, 1);
 alert("length: " + array.length);
 alert("removed element's 'a': " + element.a);   
}
```

I get:

```
3
a1
2
undefined
```

Why do I always get "undefined"? The splice method is supposed to remove the defined element(s) and return it / them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `shift` to accomplish this - it removes and returns the first element in an array.

Your problem is that splice returns an array so your code would have to be:

```
alert("removed element's 'a': " + element[0].a);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this and it works. But why my code doesn't?

Comment: @Hunter I updated my answer to explain why your code doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

`splice` returns a array of the removed elements.

this should work

```
alert("removed element's 'a': " + element[0].a);
```